# Question on the Riesz -Schauder theorem .

Tags: functional-analysis

If $ T \in B(X)$  then i am trying to prove the following property of fredholm operator . 
a) The kernel of $T$ is finite dimensional :

to show this let $S=id_X - T$ , we know that from the definition of fredholm operator $S$ is compact . let $x_n$ be a sequence in unit ball of $Kern(T)$ , then since $S$ is compact , we know that there exists a subsequence $x_k$ of $x_n$ such that $Sx_k \to y$ in $X$. then $0=Tx_k=x_k + Sx_k$ which implies that $x_k$ converges , because $Sx_k$ converges . 
which implies that $x_k$ converges to $y$ in $kern(T)$ .

b) ran($T$) is closed , and $X/ ran($T$)$ is finite dimensional . 
Can someone help me how to prove this ? 
Thanks  a lot for your help .

Comment: See here (Theorem 35.25): http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CE4QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucsd.edu%2F~bdriver%2F231-02-03%2FLecture_Notes%2Fcompact.pdf&ei=nNVaUaXVFZK10AHproCQDA&usg=AFQjCNEMGYLnUxfPFkZ0OeYIoKGsy6sXjA&sig2=HfHkqNN9gIROCP-jM-ipJA